# Rotate a div in order to make it resposive

Tags: html, css

I have a div that contains a menu in the middle of my page. My problem is to make that  responsive.My idea is to rotate it horizontally but still the buttons into it to work. So in this way it will be responsive.

Here's me css code:

```
 .content .middle-content{
        text-align: center;
    }
    .content .middle-content .prev{
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
    .content .middle-content .icon{
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        margin-top: 15px;
    }
    .content .middle-content .next{
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        margin-top: 50px;
    }
```

and my html code:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="middle-content"> 
            <hr class="vertical-line-top">
            <div class="prev">
                <a style="cursor:pointer;" id="prev">
                <img src="img/icon-01.png"   >
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="icon gif">
                <a href="#"  id="info1">
                <img src="img/icon-02.png" >
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
                <a href="#" id="info2">
                <img src="img/icon-03.png">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
                <a href="#" id="info3">
                <img src="img/icon-04.png">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
                <a href="#" id="info4">
                <img src="img/icon-05.png">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
                <a href="#" id="info5">
                <img src="img/icon-06.png">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
                <a href="#" id="info6">
                <img src="img/icon-07.png">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
                <a href="#" id="info7">
                <img src="img/icon-08.png">
                </a>
            </div>            
            <div class="icon">
                <a href="#" id="info8">
                <img src="img/icon-09.png">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="next" >
                <a style="cursor:pointer;" id="next">
                <img src="img/icon-10.png">
                </a>
            </div>
            <hr class="vertical-line-bottom">
        </div>
    </div>
```

I attached a jsfiddle  just to give the idea how it looks in general, they're three divs left that contain a picture and some text, the middle div and the right.

Can anyone help me to make it responsive, i tried  it but no chance? [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/egzontina/ff0k9j45/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We would need to see more code to reproduce it in your site however given the code you gave, you could set a media query and then float the elements left:

```
    @media (max-width: 400px){
.icon, .next, .prev{float: left;}       

    }
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ff0k9j45/2/

Comment: Yeah it still works by adjusting the width a bit https://jsfiddle.net/ff0k9j45/6/ you will need to remove the lines and stuff but this will answer your question.

Comment: in my project is not working evend that i added that  code!

Comment: Yes i know, but in my project that is not working very good, the icons are looking terrible!

Comment: If it works in your fiddle you provided, how in the world would I be able to figure out what it is doing on your site? I am not psychic.

Comment: o man hhh first thank you! I know that it was a weird answer. I mean even in jsfiddle the icons are not displayed in one line  the first and the last especially ..

Comment: is possible to hide those two lines: i tired like this but i couldn't : @media(max-width: 950px){
    .vertical-line-top .vertical-line-bottom{ visibility: hidden;}
}

Comment: Use `display:none`. `visibility: hidden;` will hide the element but keep the placeholder there, whereas  `display:none` will just remove it from the page.